# How to use pool tablets to shock well

Tags: well-pump, well, chlorine

I decided to shock my well to make sure there wasn't any bacteria in the well.

Originally I was going to use liquid bleach but I spoke with a well person and they told me to crush up a pool chlorine tablet and drop the pellets into the well. This way the tablets will make it all the way to the bottom of the well.

I've since done so and ran my water until I smelled chlorine and turned it off.

Problem is, I could barely smell the chlorine, it's not very obvious if it made it into the system.

Then I decided to test how quickly the pool tablets will dissolve. I put some pellets in a bucket of water and it's been several hours and they still have not fully dissolved. I looked up online and it says pool tablets can take up to a week to dissolve.

Does this mean I'm screwed and will have chlorine in my water for at least a week? Why was it recommended to use pool tablets? Resources online even say to use them. Am I missing something?

Comment: The right way to use them, if using them at all, is to dissolve them in a bucket of water first. Too late now...

Comment: The solid tablets can easily take a week or more to dissolve (the larger 3" ones take longer than the smaller 1" ones), but crushing them up into granules should speed that up significantly. If you crushed them up reasonably well (1/8" granules or smaller" I'd be surprised if they take more than a couple of hours.

Comment: They are used in pools.  People do drink pool water.  It is the amount per unit that matters, not that there is a tiny bit in it.  Run some water for some time and it should be okay.  Dissolving one in a glass of water and then drinking it not so good.

Comment: Did you have your water tested for quality before deciding to do this? Are you certain you're not killing good bacteria along with the bad? Remember, most folk are well intentioned, many are misinformed, and some are down right malicious. The important thing is to be able to discern the difference.

Comment: leave drinking water out in a pitcher in the sun to remove chlorine. or boil it off.  Brita pitchers would work too. you can also get test kits for pools for cheap, typically combo Cl/Ph test kits.

Answer (score 1):

You can find advice for everything on line even things that can kill you “tide pods” ring a bell

I have worked with a certified well tester / inspector and he ALWAYS uses liquid bleach or liquid chlorine in some cases up to 5 gallons but usually 2-3.

Add chlorine run water until you smell it then lit it sit in the well & plumbing 8 hours is great over night is better.

After sitting in the system the well & plumbing needs to be flushed until you can not smell it then some more.

While flushing he usually does the flow testing that requires 3 hours full flow although the chlorine is usually out of the well in an hour it’s not worth it to take a chance so let the water run, it can also help you know the health of your well by measuring the flow rate.

Don’t freak if your well is only pushing 5 gpm when it used to push 8 according to the well log. When they do the test on a new well the pressures are set higher and a fresh pressure tank gets better results.

Or if your pump is cycling at all with full flow this means the actual full flow max is higher.

I would not use tablets and the chlorine systems I have seen use a tank and liquid, I have seen 1 that used granular chlorine but the owner had it turned off and we were removing it for a tanked system.

If some similar sized crushed tablets dissolved in a bucket the well should be ok as the fresh water flowing into the well will dissolve the pieces faster than static water that is at a higher chlorine level.